# 120VAC buried splice

Tags: voltage

I have a romex cable feeding an outdoor yard light.

It was cut, I spliced it, soldered it and wrapped it with tape. Is there a way to splice and bury it safely to code?

If not, I'll need to dig a 30 foot trench to replace the whole length.

Comment: https://www.wikihow.com/Splice-Wire Method #3 is my prefered way. Make sure the glue from the sleeve covers the entire cable all around, to prevent water from entering the splice.

Comment: Go to your local hardware store and buy an underground splice.

Comment: Duplicate of https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/170102/97780

Comment: @DaveTweed it was already on here so why create a duplicate?

Comment: Flagged for mods. The other version has a live user attached, so it's probably the one to keep.