# Splice in buried line to well

Tags: wiring, well

I am faced with the possibility of replacing my well.  I'm hoping to not have to run a new buried power line from the house.  Can a buried cable be spliced?  If not, then a new well has to be located along the powerline to the house.  If so, how is it done?

(My thinking is that if the well is closer to the house, I only have to dig up from the old well enough cable to rebury it to route to the new well.  If I can't splice, then I have to put in a new power line from the new well all the way to the house, a distance of about 200 feet, plus weaving about a bunch of trees.)

A similar question was asked here: [120VAC buried splice](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/170108/120vac-buried-splice)
but received no answers.

Comment: I recently had to do this myself and I found that the water line from the well into the house was in deteriorated condition.  You may want to check yours, and yes that may mean digging, but as long as you're going through all this, you might as well fix everything at once and not worry about it again for another 30 years or so.  I had a horizontal boring company bore in a new water line and a conduit so that I could pull a new wire to the well.

Comment: Why do you believe it would be helpful to locate the well near the power service line is? You cannot tap the service line.

Comment: I didn't say service line.  powerline = cable from the house to the well, as compared to water line = pipe from house to the well. sorry I wasn't clear.

Answer (score 1):

Please see my comment on your original question but yes, direct buried cable can be spliced with the correct components.  Check with a local electrical supply shop (not a big-box home center) and get their advice on the correct product for your local area and the wire you are splicing.  Here is a link to an example of this type of product:

[Direct Burial Splice Kit Example](https://www.graybar.com/store/en/gb/termination-tape-splicing-and-marking/splice-kits?productBeginIndex=0&orderBy=0&pageView=grid&pageSize=50&pageNumber=1&facetId=)

Comment: The big box stores carry the same splice kit as my local electric supply store but the big box store charges 2$ more. Unfortunately platt will only sell to electricians. So you might have to may 20$ for the kit. The kit I mentioned can handle 4 wires in 14 to 8 awg wire sizes.